# Woocommerce multiple variations - drop logic control

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have to display 3 sets of variation of products on woocommerce, e.g. Finish Type A, B, C. Each finish type contains some options & each variation has it's own price.

However, visitors have to select all 3 variations now before a price can show up. 
How can I show the price of each variation by choosing only one variation?

In short:

1. I have multiple attributes as variables.
2. The variables are not linked to each other. Each variable has its own price.
3. Can I stop the default logic control for multiple variables and show prices like having only one variable?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you search for the plugin and build in feature for Woocommerce, Woocmmerce is a big plugin that has many add-ons and integrated plugin, please try and share your problem here.

Comment: Yes, I have searched a lot of plugins. Basically they dealt with the logic controll of the different variations. But my problem is I want to drop those logics. I just want it plain & simple.
I want to show each variation a price, while the variations are grouped in multiple attributes.

Comment: That is simply not possible logically… think about…

Answer (score 0):

Increase WooCommerce Variation Limit

```
`function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold($qty,$product)
{
  return 100;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 100, 2 );`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I tested it.
It seems that my question is not related to the variation limit.
Anyway, thanks for your reply.